# Select <a> values from ul li within a jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery variable as the following

```
var $data = "<li id='root'><a href='#'>Root node</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Child node</a></li></ul></li><li id='root2'><a href='#'>Root 2 node</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Child 2 Parent Node</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Child 2 child1</a></li></ul><ul><li><a href='#'>Child 2 child2</a></li></ul></li></ul></li>";
```

I want to fetch the values of each `<a href=#>` values and push it into an array.

Can any body help???

Comment: Do you mean the inner contents?

Comment: @Hogan yes the inner `<a>` values from the variable. For example in this case I need, dataarray=[Root Node, Child Node, Root 2 Node, ......] and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = $($data).find('a[href="#"]').map(function(){
     return $(this).text()
}).get();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tZNXP/) (open the console)

Comment: Don't forget about `.get()` ;)

Comment: @dystroy I console logged your `arr` it returned ["Root node", "Child node", "Root 2 node", "Child 2 Parent Node", "Child 2 child1", "Child 2 child2", prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[6], context: undefined]. What is "prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[6], context: undefined" ?

Comment: @Debopam It means that without the `get` (pointed by VisioN), the result isn't exactly an array but just array-like. For most purposes it works the same but if you want a real array, the get is needed (see updated answer).

Comment: @VisioN I was pondering its addition. It's not always needed, it depends on how you use the result.

Comment: @dystroy Yes Exactly. I used it like this

`var sources = [];
  
  var values = $("a[href='#']", $data).map(function() {
   sources.push({
    'label' : $(this).text(),
    'value' : $(this).text()
   });
      return $(this).text();
  });`

Actually I wanted to have a autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var values = $("a[href='#']", $data).map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vp7tN/